# add php variable into ajax

Tags: php, ajax

how to work with php variable without jQuery?
My test.php file:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$language = 'zzz';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<button onclick = "setCookie()">test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>    
<script>
function setCookie() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "setCookie.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php
echo 'session: ' . $_SESSION['xxx'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and my setCookie.php file is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['xxx'] = $language;
?>
```

If I put some simple echo statement in setCookie.php, it works and appears on my website. But why it can`t assign $language value to session['xxx']?

Comment: Because `$language;` is no where defined in your `setCookie.php` page. Try like this and check :- `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);
session_start();
$language = "eng";
$_SESSION['xxx'] = $language;
?>`

Comment: that was my point to get $language from test.php to setCookie.php. Looks like setCookie.php can read only session variables. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse ajax will be new request when its call so you have to pass value with it.
 try this:

**test.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$language = 'zzz';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<button onclick = "setCookie()">test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>    
<script>
function setCookie() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
    language = '<?=$language?>'; //get value
  xhttp.open("POST", "setCookie.php", true); 
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("language=" + language); //send as post params
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php
echo 'session: ' . $_SESSION['xxx'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**setCookie.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$language = $_POST['language']; //retrive value
$_SESSION['xxx'] = $language; //assign to session
?>
```

Comment: the value 'zzz' is assigned to $_SESSION['xxx'] immediately after test.php was loaded, not after button onclick. I`m gonna look at this again

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your `setCookie.php` file like below.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['xxx'] = $_POST['language'];
?>
```

Comment: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\druhy\setCookie.php on line 3

Comment: try this  **$language = $_POST['language']; $_SESSION['xxx'] = $language**

Comment: the same result